# Java JSpinner increase value with down arrow

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have a JSpinner that has all integers as `model`. I want it's value to increase with the down arrow and value to decrease with up arrow,which is the exact opposite of the default usage.

I have already done this using a variable that has the previous value and added a `Change Listener`. Whenever a value changes i compare it to the previous. If it's about to increase i instead decrease it and vice versa.

I wanted to know if there is another way of doing it. Like a `listener` who knows which arrow is pressed.

Comment: This sounds highly counter-intuitive and not the 'path of least surprise' for the user. How does it make sense to have the spinner work this way? I don't doubt there are situations in which this might be the *exact* right thing to to do, so humor me, and explain this one.

Comment: The spinner is highligting the lines of a text. So when a user presses up the value increases and the next line is highlighted. But from the GUI prespective you press up and the line highlited is the one below the one that was previously highlighted. When the user presses down i want to highlight the line below so i have to increase the value. I want the arrow to represent whether you want the below  or above line to be highligted not the number of the line to highlight. I don't know if that was the "humor" you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes that does make sense. Sorry for the confusion I introduced with the phrase 'humor me'. It has a specific meaning that might not be immediately obvious, but [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78823/7423) explains it well.

Comment: Totally misundestood you. Sorry. Thanks for the additional knowledge on top of your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(5, 1, 100, -1); // Note: -ve step
```

Comment: (1+) Seriously? I went to the bathroom by taking the bus. lol.

Answer (score 2):

[Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61659632/6579265) is the way to go. This is another way to achieve it via a `ChangeListener`, since you mentioned it.

A `ChangeListener` fires every time the value changes in the spinner field.

The steps are:

1. Keep a field reference of its current value.
2. Detect the new value in listener
3. If the new value is higher than the old value, it means the ↑ arrow pressed
4. Otherwise, it means the ↓ arrow pressed
5. According to the change, set the opposite value

An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of what I mean:

```
public class SpinnerExample extends JFrame {
    private int oldValue;

    public SpinnerExample() {
        super("");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                int newValue = (int) spinner.getValue();
                spinner.removeChangeListener(this);
                if (newValue > oldValue) //next value button pressed
                    spinner.setValue(oldValue - (newValue - oldValue));
                else
                    spinner.setValue(oldValue + (oldValue - newValue));
                oldValue = (int) spinner.getValue();
                spinner.addChangeListener(this);
            }
        });
        add(spinner);

        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SpinnerExample().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Note that the listener is removed before changing the value and after the change is added again. If you dont remove-change-add the listener, you will end up with a StackOverFlow error since changing the value will fire the listener again and again.

Also, remember that `this` in line `spinner.removeChangeListener(this);` refers to the `ChangeListener`. Converting this listener to a lambda expression:

```
spinner.addChangeListener(e -> {
    int newValue = (int) spinner.getValue();
    spinner.removeChangeListener(this);
    if (newValue > oldValue) //next value button pressed
        spinner.setValue(oldValue - (newValue - oldValue));
    else
        spinner.setValue(oldValue + (oldValue - newValue));
    oldValue = (int) spinner.getValue();
    System.out.println("oldValue:" + oldValue);
    spinner.addChangeListener(this);
});
```

you will not able to remove the listener, since the `this` will be a reference to `SpinnerExample` instance and not the listener. **Long story short, keep it an anonymous class and not a lambda.**

Another way to accomplish is to switch the handlers/listeners of these buttons (probably reflection will have to interfere), but it will require a lot more effort. Plus there is no guarantee that will work for other look and feels, since they are initiated in `<LookAndFeel>`-`ComboBoxUI`.

Comment: Plus one for the effort you put in. I hope the bus ride was pleasant. ;)

Comment: I have a more complex model from what i explained so your answer fits better and i will follow your solution. I ticked andrews answer however because most people who gonna come in here will be searching for his answer. Thank you!

Comment: @KostasThanasis No problem, my fellow UOI student :) Zarras?